# WCF Service Operation with Closed Generic return type not visible in client

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have created a WCF Service Operation with a closed generic return type. I was hoping to refer to the closed generic as it's design time name, not run time name. Example

The service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Food<BurritoKinds> GetBurrito();
}

[DataContract]
public class Food<T>
{
    public T Detail { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum BurritoKinds
{
    [EnumMember]
    Bean,
    [EnumMember]
    Beef
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Food<BurritoKinds> GetBurrito()
    {
        return new Food<BurritoKinds> { Detail = BurritoKinds.Beef };
    }
}
```

And the client

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new Service1Client();
        Food<BurritoKinds> burrito = client.GetBurrito();         //Compile Error
        FoodOfBurritoKindsSSCqoCp1 burrito2 = client.GetBurrito();//Works Fine
    }
```

I want to use `Food<BurritoKinds>` instead of having to use `FoodOfBurritoKindsSSCqoCp1` when referring to the type. What am I missing to allow this or is it possible without creating a new DLL just to hold that Generic and sharing it with both the Service and Client?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx
Jeff Barnes points out that wsdl (and not so much wcf) limits the use of generic types: to the consumer they always appear as concrete types. Different concrete types may however be generated by generics in your .Net-code, as is the case with your FoodOfBurritoKindsSSCqoCp1 type. Note that use can specify the name of the generated type using the DataContract attribute, e.g. [DataContract(Name = "FoodOf{0}"], which should result in FoodOfBurritoKinds in the wsdl for the consumer.